# Moving Validation rule to Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I want to move this validation rule to trigger the Validation rule is

```
AND(
    LR_Disease_Condition__c = $Label.Label_for_Disease_Condition,
    NOT(CONTAINS( $User.LHJ__c , CA_Local_Health_Jurisdiction__c)),
    CONTAINS($UserRole.DeveloperName,'Supervisor'),
    $User.Opted_In_To_Cross_Jurisdiction_Sharing__c
```

Eariler the `Opted_In_To_Cross_Jurisdiction_Sharing__c` Field was a checkbox field now it is converted into a Multi Picklist value so we cannot use this validation rule and we need to move this into the trigger. Any leads would be appreciated .

Comment: Why does `Field__c` being a mulipicklist mean that you need a trigger instead of a validation rule? Moving to a trigger to do validation is generally a last resort (it's harder to find the source of a validation error when you use `addError()` in a trigger, the trigger needs unit tests, etc...). `INCLUDES()` is a function that is specifically meant to work on multipicklists.

Comment: I believe you cannot reference such a field in any formula, including for `Validation Rules`. As far as I know, `INCLUDES` is supported in SOQL only. That said, how to write validation logic in `Apex Triggers` is fairly well documented, and this post shows a lack of research or any good faith effort to solve the problem by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below expression to fetch Custom Label in trigger

```
String labelForDisease = Label.Label_for_Disease_Condition

/*UserInfo.getUserId() will return the Id of the Current User executing the transaction*/

Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, LHJ__c, Opted_In_To_Cross_Jurisdiction_Sharing__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]);   

/*UserInfo.getUserRoleId() returns the context user's role ID.*/

**Map<Id, UserRole> userRoleMap = new Map<Id, UserRole>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserRoleId()]);**
```

Iterate on the `Trigger.New` List and use if blocks to check conditions and inside the if blocks you may use `addError('Error Message')` method to throw an error if the condition fails and the record will not update.

For Example:

```
trigger TriggerName on Object_Name__c (before insert, before update){    //Must be on Before Insert and before update events
    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, LHJ__c, Opted_In_To_Cross_Jurisdiction_Sharing__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]);
    Map<Id, UserRole> userRoleMap = new Map<Id, UserRole>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserRoleId()]);

    String labelForDisease =  = Label.Label_for_Disease_Condition;

    for(Object_Name__c rec: Trigger.New){
    
        if (!userMap.get(UserInfo.getUserId()).LHJ__c.contains(rec.CA_Local_Health_Jurisdiction__c)) {
             rec.addError('Validation error Message');
        }

        if (record.LR_Disease_Condition__c != labelForDisease) {
            rec.addError('LR Disease Condition is not correct');
        }
    }

}
```

Add more if blocks as per your validation rule.